# How can I define a return type of a lambda function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, lambda, typedef, dartz

I try to create a repository with type safe parameters. For this, I created the function parameter as a typedef and use the [Dartz package](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz), to be able to return either a failure or the desired result.

The issue is, that I have to create a specific function, if I want to pass an argument of the typedef type.

```
typedef FailOrModel<T> = Future<Either<Failure, T>> Function();

class Repository {

  Future<Either<Failure, T>> _runAfterSync<T>(FailOrModel func) async {
    await synchronize().then(
      (value) => value.fold(
        (failure) {
          log.e('Synchronization error: $failure');
        },
        (_) {},
      ),
    );
    return await func();
  }
  
  Future<Either<Failure, Storage>> getStorage(int id) async {
    // Todo: Find out why lambda does not work
    Future<Either<Failure, Storage>> func() async {
      try {
        final model = await localDataSource.getStorage(id);
        return Right(model);
      } on CacheException {
        log.e('Could not load storage with id $id');
        return Left(CacheFailure());
      }
    }

    return await _runAfterSync<Storage>(func);
  }
}
```

When I pass the identical function body as a lambda function directly, as I would like to, I get a runtime error:

```
  Future<Either<Failure, Storage>> getStorage(int id) async {
    return await _runAfterSync<Storage>(() async {
      try {
        final model = await localDataSource.getStorage(id);
        return Right(model);
      } on CacheException {
        log.e('Could not load storage with id $id');
        return Left(CacheFailure());
      }
    });
  }
```

> type 'Right<Failure, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Either<Failure, Storage>>'

It is not a big deal, but maybe someone could enlighten me, how I am able to use a lambda function here, or why I get this error, if I use a lambda function.

Comment: One thing I notice is that `_runAfterSync` takes a `FailOrModel` parameter, which really means `FailOrModel<dynamic>`.  Does it help at all if you fix `_runAfterSync`'s parameter to be `FailOrModel<T>`?

Comment: Well yes, that fixed it. Now I feel stupid. Completely overlooked that. Thank you very much for pointing this out. It really bothered me, for some reason, that I had to write an extra function.
If you would like, you could post your comment as an answer, and I will mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The expected return type of `getStorage(int)` from a Future is `Either<Failure, Storage>`. The mismatch occurs because you're trying to return `Right<Failure, dynamic>`.

As what have been mentioned in the comments, you can pass `FailOrModel<T>` in `_runAfterSync` to solve the issue.